# Remove rows with an NA using dplyr in DB

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm still getting accustomed to the limited/different data wrangling tools available through `dplyr` when working directly in a remote database vs in a data frame stored in R's memory. Thus my question:

How do you filter out rows of a table where a certain column has an NA?

Given an example dataframe `mydata` with columns A and B, for example, in base R it'd be

```
mydata[!is.na(mydata$A),]
```

In `dplyr` with the data stored*in-memory* it'd be:

```
mydata %>%
   filter(!is.na(A))
```

However, when I try to execute the above statement in-database, I get an error saying

> Error: n not greater than 0L

I'm aware of `na.omit()` but I want the flexibility to be able to filter over whatever column(s) I need.

Comment: @akrun I get ```Error in UseMethod("slice_") : 
  no applicable method for 'slice_' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_postgres', 'tbl_sql', 'tbl')" ```

Comment: I doubt your DB is storing `NA` akin to how R stores `NA`. It's probably more like `A != "NA"` in your DB. A table schema would be useful here.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen great point. I was assuming that NA was NA, but I can see why it wouldn't. Suppose though that NA as I see it in R is a missing value in SQL, say, NULL.

Comment: Same deal, R doesn't store in the same manner as SQL. So the filter would likely be text based. There is no good answer to your question, because "it depends" if you're exectuting in the DB or after you've pulled data to R. SQL != R.

Comment: Thanks @BrandonBertelsen. As my question says I'm executing in the DB. Your point is well taken and I'll get clarification on the schema.

Comment: `describe table_name;`